# Associate many records to one with has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to associate several dinners to a meal with a `has_many: through` relationship when the user hits "save". My question is not with the mechanics of `has_many: through`.  I know how to set that up and I have it working in the Rails console, but I just don't know how to set up the view to associate several records at once.

I have models set up like this:

```rb
class Dinner < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :user
    has_many :meals 
    has_many :meal_plans, through: :meals
end

class MealPlan < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :meals
    has_many :dinners, through: :meals
end

class Meal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dinner
  belongs_to :meal_plan
end
```

With a meal plan controller:

```rb
    def create 

      @meal_plan = current_user.meal_plans.build(meal_plan_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @meal_plan.save
         format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Dinner was successfully created.' }
         end
      end
    end

    private 

    def meal_plan_params
        params.require(:meal_plan).permit(dinners: []) 
    end
```

My question is about the view, in the new view, I create a `@meal_plan` and I want to pass several different dinners into the meal plan.  Below the `value: @dinners` is just 7 random dinners pulled from the Dinners table.

```rb
 <%= form_with model: @meal_plan do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field(:dinners, value: @dinners)%>


    <%= f.submit 'Save'%>
  <% end %>
```

Again, I've gotten this to work by running something like `usr.meal_plans.create(dinners: [d1, d2])`` in the Rails console but I don't

Answer (score 1):

You can use the form option helpers to generate selects or checkboxes:

```
<%= form_with model: @meal_plan do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :dinner_ids, Dinner.all, :id, :name, multiple: true %>
  <%= f.collection_checkboxes :dinner_ids, Dinner.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save'%>
<% end %>
```

`_ids` is a special setter / getter generated by ActiveRecord for has many assocations. You pass an array of ids and AR will take care of inserting/removing the join table rows (meals).

You also need to change the name in your params whitelist:

```
def meal_plan_params
  params.require(:meal_plan).permit(dinner_ids: []) 
end
```

If you want to to pass an array through hidden inputs you can do it like so:

```
<% @dinners.each do |dinner| >
  <%= hidden_field_tag "meal_plans[dinner_ids][]", dinner.id %>
<% end %>
```

See [Pass arrays & objects via querystring the Rack/Rails way](https://coderwall.com/p/uh8kiw/pass-arrays-objects-via-querystring-the-rack-rails-way) for an explaination of how this works.